# CPA auto bid API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

i heard somthing about an option to upload CPA campaigns with auto bid. couldnt find this option in the API support.

did anyone hear anything about it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a property on adset level. Set the property is_autobid to true when creating the adset. According to: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-campaign